# Undefined variable in a template file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new here, so please bear with me.

Am trying to run a project built using the codeigniter.

The project is an online registration system,but am getting the undefined variable error in some parts of my page.

Please if you got the time to go over the project and help me out I will be very grateful.

Here is the link to the whole system.

NB:It contains the exported database already( the database is called 'orsdb' )

Cheers!!!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByYO-aax6KH3cnJNRnBsNEgwd1k

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is a Q&A site where people ask specific programming questions and members here volunteer to answer them.  Since you are new, I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  That being said, we'd prefer if you could provide the *exact* error message you are seeing along with the code that is creating it (or rather a small example that recreates the error).  Unfortunately, no one here is going to download your entire project and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check every variable in your CI view part before printing it, you can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check you variable is either define or not. Example -

`<?php echo isset($var) ? $var:""; ?>`
You can also use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check variables.

Another thing is if your variable is always undefined then you must check your array which contains data fetching from database in CI controller and print the array to check your all required value does exist or not. If not exists then check your SQL query whether it fetches your required data or not.

Comment: Thanks mate,lemme work on that and see what happens.